# The Legendary Enormous Boulder Scene

Tags: first-appearance

Everyone knows this scene! Indiana Jones narrowly escapes death by a huge rolling boulder in the *Raiders of the Lost Ark*. However I recently watched the original *Journey to the Center of the Earth* with James Mason again and was delighted to find the same scene is used here were he too and his party encounter the same situation ([Scene starts at 1:06](http://www.tcm.com/mediaroom/video/502798/Journey-To-The-Center-Of-The-Earth-Movie-Clip-A-Slight-Tremor.html))

I'm pretty sure I've seen the same scene used in another movie as well. Thought it could have been used in *King Solomon's Mines* (1985) but I was mistaken.

My question is what is the first film to use this situation and how times has this been used in movie history?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're speaking of is the [Indy Escapes trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/IndyEscape), which apparently debuted in the Buster Keaton film [Seven Chances (1925)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0016332/), although it was styrofoam rocks that the hero was running from.

The scene in question can be seen [here](http://youtu.be/zTwfCyWKYYc?t=49m46s).